# como fazer um campo de mensagem com botões de formatação

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com algo em mente aqui e preciso da ideia de vocês
quero colocar um campo no meu sistema onde posso salvar feedbacks de alunos, adicionar imagens e formatar fontes, este campo de mensagem que terá um texto do feedback do aluno, será um campo vindo do MYSQL, quero que na tela eu possa formatar esse texto e deixá-lo mais bonito, mais quando eu sair e entrar no sistema, quero que a formatação feita no texto anteriormente permaneça, alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Sua pergunta precisa ser mais específica. A comuniadade do stackoverflow, não é uma comunidade que desenvolve tutoriais ou promove discussões. Nós procuramos responder perguntas específicas, de usuários que estão procurando como resolver determinado problema.

Comment: Minha pergunta foi especifica, preciso de um campo de edição com formatação e que fique salvo até depois de atualizar no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se bem pelo o que entendi você quer um WYSIWYG.
Bom, segue:

Recomendo então o plugin CKEditor. Antes de implementar, pode conferir aqui meu exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/richellyitalo/g65z24wr/2/.

Segue o código:

    `<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script> CKEDITOR.replace( 'campo1' ); </script>
    <textarea id="campo1">Valor inicial aqui</textarea>`

Comment: Muito legal, como que eu faço a implementação?

Comment: Da mesma forma que está acima, apenas substituindo o nome do campo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito